# Could ever imagine and could ever have imagined

Tags: subjunctives, perfect-constructions

Please tell me the difference between the following sentences and also when to use them.

1. That was the best thing I could ever have imagined.
2. That was the best thing I could imagine.
3. This is the best thing I can ever imagine.

Thank you.

Comment: (3.) should also be "could", because in all three cases, you are in the realm of the hypothetical.

Comment: In the wake of something really good happening, you could use any one of the three.

Comment: But I have still not understood the nuance. Can you please elaborate?

Comment: I don't think there *are* any nuance differences – they all pretty much convey the same sentiment in a rather indistinguishable way.